# What does "property=''" do?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I'm working on a Drupal site/theme. The CSS and PHP modifications are fairly easy; they just take a little time to learn and get working exactly how I want.
However, I'm having issues applying CSS styles to some elements because of what I think is a property function.

The code looks like `<h2 property="dc:title" datatype="" class="node-title">`.

What is a property function and what does it do or control within the page? Also how can I modify or remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a property function; it's an attribute that is used from RDFa, and that is added from the RDF module.

The easier way to remove those attributes is to disable the module, but I would not suggest doing it, as the purpose of that module is to enrich your content with metadata to let other applications better understand its relationships and attributes.

Alternatively, if the problem is just with that property, used for the nodes, then you can implement code similar to the following one:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_node(&$variables) { 
  if (isset($variables['title_attributes_array'])) {
    $variables['title_attributes_array']['property'] = NULL;
  }
}
```

The module should be executed after the RDF module, to allow its hook to be executed after the one implemented by the RDF module.

I have not seen any compatibility problem between the attributes added by the RDF module and the JavaScript code executed by Drupal core or third-party modules. It would probably be the case to investigate why you are having problems with the JavaScript code when those HTML attributes are added.

Comment: Could the property value effect or make css values hard to assign to an element? The style sheet updates are working fine and take effect on pretty much everything, except they either don't get applied or I have trouble getting them to work on elements with property="" within them. Sorry, but I'm new to Drual and have never really used XHTML except in a few tiny bits so I'm kind of needing to ask questions.

Comment: @JackMcE Drupal assigns a CSS style even to HTML elements with that attribute; I would say that attribute doesn't have any effect, on CSS styles.

Comment: Thanks and that is good to know. Guess I just have to dig for the actual location of what is preventing my style issues.

Answer (score 1):

in your css file, put:

```
h2[property="dc:title"]{color:#FFFFFF;}
```

or if it is a link, you may need:

```
h2[property="dc:title"] a {color:#FFFFFF;}
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to style your elements based on DC properties.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
Regarding your answer, I second @cherouvim 's comment that RDF stuff should not be used to style. they don't work in older browsers and mainly, they are not for styling purposes.

Answer (score 0):

From wikipedia, check out [RDFa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDFa)

> RDFa (or Resource Description
>   Framework – in – attributes) is a W3C
>   Recommendation that adds a set of
>   attribute-level extensions to XHTML
>   for embedding rich metadata within Web
>   documents.

It is basically a way to add more metadata to XHTML docs for better semantics.

Comment: Well it is good to know that it is an XHTML property, now it is really a matter of tracking it down and modifying it within Drupal. I'm building off of Zen which is nice, but finding things can be difficult. Do you think such xhtml info is in the Zen core or theme settings if you know?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any experience of Zen core and Drupal to help you there.